# How do i fix Cannot read property 'channels' of undefined

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I want to make a discord bot program. when someone new goes to the server they have to type !daftar to be able to enjoy the server. and when they type !daftar message list will appear on #welcome channel. but I get an error that is in the title. here is my code

```
const { GuildMember } = require("discord.js");

module.exports = {
    name: 'daftar',
    description: "This is for add roles to a member",
    execute(message, args) {
        let role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === "Members")

        if (message.member.roles.cache.some(r => r.name === "Members")) {
            message.channel.send('Kamu sudah menjadi MEMBER Di grup ini');
        } else {
            message.member.roles.add('817360044622217276');
            message.member.roles.remove('817965925122048010');
            message.channel.send('Baiklah silahkan menikmati Server');
            GuildMember.guild.channels.cache.get('817957997312737290').send(`Selamat Datang <@${GuildMember.user.id}>`)

        }


    }
}
```

Comment: [All](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66503101/how-do-i-fix-cannot-read-property-fetch-of-undefined) of your [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66502460/how-do-i-fix-typeerror-cannot-read-property-get-of-undefined) seem to be the same, just with different property names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GuildMember` is not exactly defined. Yes, you are destructuring it as the property of `discord.js`, but it's not exactly defined as who the member actually is. Right now it's just an empty object that belongs to no one, meaning that it also has no properties itself as it does not know what it refers to.

Assuming that you're wanting to give the role to the member who typed this command, you'd have to make the `GuildMember` object the property of the `Message` object that is defined as `message` in your parameters. We can get this object using the `member` property of `message` => `message.member`.

Now, assuming that the channel you're looking to send the message to is found in the same guild as the `message` object, there is no sense behind using a `GuildMember` object to find a certain channel, when we can instead use the `Message` object, as seen below:

#### Final Code

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'daftar',
    description: "This is for add roles to a member",
    execute(message, args) {
        let role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === "Members")

        if (message.member.roles.cache.some(r => r.name === "Members")) {
            message.channel.send('Kamu sudah menjadi MEMBER Di grup ini');
        } else {
            message.member.roles.add('817360044622217276');
            message.member.roles.remove('817965925122048010');
            message.channel.send('Baiklah silahkan menikmati Server');
            message.guild.channels.cache.get('817957997312737290').send(`Selamat Datang <@${GuildMember.user.id}>`)    
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. i forget about it. i just watching the tutorial on youtube. so thank you so much

Comment: No problem :)
I'd appreciate if you could mark my answer as correct so it could be visible for other people as well.